# AngularJS with ui.router $state not working when async

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a problem with the use of [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org) and [ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/).

I have an application where basically a user write informations, which are send to the server, and when the server answer I change the current state to be a list of channels.

My problem is that by using an asynchroneus system I lose the ability to change the current state, without any error, demos :

The following demo is the one that is OK, because it does not use an asynchroneus system (see console):

code :
http://jsfiddle.net/dievardump/x2tMT/

demo full :
http://jsfiddle.net/dievardump/x2tMT/embedded/result/

This one is the one that is not ok (see console).

code :
http://jsfiddle.net/dievardump/f9rSQ/

demo full :
http://jsfiddle.net/dievardump/f9rSQ/embedded/result/

The ONLY difference between these two samples is in the declaration of the state "platform.channels" :

```
console.log('goes to platform.game');
$state.go('platform.game', {
    type: 'gameType',
    id: 1
});
```

VS

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('should go to platform.game');
    $state.go('platform.game', {
        type: 'gameType',
        id: 1
    });
}, 1000);
```

Full demos easy to import locally :

Working :

```
<div ui-view></div>
<script>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/signin");

        $stateProvider
            .state('platform', {
                url: '/platform',
                data: {
                    permissions: ['auth']
                },
                template: "<section class='platform'>platform<div ui-view></div></section>",
                controller: function($state) {
                    console.log('platformController');
                }
            });
});

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('signin', {
            url: "/signin",
            template: "<section id='connect' class='connect'><form name='connection' action='' ng-submit='login(connection)'><input placeholder='Choose a nickname' ng-model='nickname' autocomplete='off' /><button><span>Send</span></button></form><p class='error' ng-show='error != null'>{{error}}</p></section>",
            controller: function($scope, $state) {
                $scope.error = null;
                $scope.nickname = null;

                $scope.login = function(form) {
                    var value = $scope.nickname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
                    if (value.length >= 3) {
                        $state.go('platform.channels');
                    } else {
                        $scope.error = 'only characters and numbers. length must be >= 3';
                    }
                }
            }
        });
});

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('platform.channels', {
        url: "/channels",
        template: "<section id='channels' class='channels'>channels</section>",
        controller: function($state) {
            console.log('channelController');
            console.log('goes to platform.game');
            $state.go('platform.game', {
                type: 'gameType',
                id: 1
            });
        }
    })
});

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('platform.game', {
            url: "/game/:type/:id",
            template: "<section id='game' class='game'>game</section>",
            controller: function() {
                console.log('gameController');
            }
        });
});


angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
</script>
```

Non working :

```
<div ui-view></div>
<script>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/signin");

        $stateProvider
            .state('platform', {
                url: '/platform',
                data: {
                    permissions: ['auth']
                },
                template: "<section class='platform'>platform<div ui-view></div></section>",
                controller: function($state) {
                    console.log('platformController');
                }
            });
});

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('signin', {
            url: "/signin",
            template: "<section id='connect' class='connect'><form name='connection' action='' ng-submit='login(connection)'><input placeholder='Choose a nickname' ng-model='nickname' autocomplete='off' /><button><span>Send</span></button></form><p class='error' ng-show='error != null'>{{error}}</p></section>",
            controller: function($scope, $state) {
                $scope.error = null;
                $scope.nickname = null;

                $scope.login = function(form) {
                    var value = $scope.nickname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
                    if (value.length >= 3) {
                        $state.go('platform.channels');
                    } else {
                        $scope.error = 'only characters and numbers. length must be >= 3';
                    }
                }
            }
        });
});

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('platform.channels', {
        url: "/channels",
        template: "<section id='channels' class='channels'>channels</section>",
        controller: function($state) {
            console.log('channelController');
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('should go to platform.game');
                $state.go('platform.game', {
                    type: 'gameType',
                    id: 1
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    })
});

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('platform.game', {
            url: "/game/:type/:id",
            template: "<section id='game' class='game'>game</section>",
            controller: function() {
                console.log('gameController');
            }
        });
});


angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
</script>
```

Any reason why $state.go does not work in the setTimeout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your demo does not work is the timeout, its simple when you cause a change out of angulars knowledge, angular stays un-aware of the changes happening and hence it wont update.

The solution is to use the angular way of doing this. angular provides `$timeout` service.

read more on that here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

working (fixed Async demo here) : http://jsfiddle.net/f9rSQ/2/

PS you should always use angular's way or ng-* directives to handle asynchronous changes things like button click event listeners won't fire if you do them via pure javascript. To make them fire you can force angular to run a `$digest` cycle which is what actually happens in a cleaner way when you use `ng-click` , `$http` etc.